# Filter lines matched on first word in line where the following line does not contain a pattern

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

**Let's say I want to filter out this:**

```
==> DEVICE 1 <==
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/28
 switchport access vlan 123
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/29
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/30
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/32
 switchport access vlan 15
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/33
==> DEVICE 2 <==
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/28
 switchport access vlan 123
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/29
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/30
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/32
 switchport access vlan 15
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/33
```

**to this:**

```
==> DEVICE 1 <==
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/28
 switchport access vlan 123
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/32
 switchport access vlan 15
==> DEVICE 2 <==
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/28
 switchport access vlan 123
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/32
 switchport access vlan 15
```

**I could go with:**

`grep switchport -B1 file` but that will not output the device name, using -B2 will sometimes output the device name, depending on the order ...

Another logic would be to filter out all lines matched on the first word in line "interface" where the next line is not followed by "switchport".

What is the best way to achieve this? Grep, Awk, sed?

Comment: `grep` is for doing `g/re/p`. `sed` is for doing `s/old/new/`. Neither of those describes what you want to do so awk is the right tool to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `awk` would be better choice for this:

```
awk '$1 == "==>"{print} $1=="switchport"{print p; print} {p=$0}' file
```

```
==> DEVICE 1 <==
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/28
 switchport access vlan 123
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/32
 switchport access vlan 15
==> DEVICE 2 <==
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/28
 switchport access vlan 123
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/32
 switchport access vlan 15
```

Comment: That works, you matched on "DEVICE", but that is not always DEVICE in my case, it can be random, so I matched it on "==>" which is always present like this: `awk '$1 == "==>"{print} $1=="switchport"{print p; print} {p=$0}'`

Comment: Thanks. Can you also explain the command, so we can all understand what is happening?

Comment: `{p=$0}` stores each of previous line in variable `p` and then when our comparison succeeds we print `p`